# WP_Query for custom post type and category_id not working

Tags: plugins, codex, the-events-calendar

I am tring to implement custom filter for The Event Calendar. I have used this code

```
$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'tribe_events',
   'meta_key' => '_EventStartDate',
   'meta_query' => array(
      array(
        'key' => '_EventStartDate',
        'value' => array( $start_date, $end_date ),
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        'type' => 'DATE'
      )
   ),
  'category__in' => array( 2, 6 )
 );

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

It will return blank post

Comment: Use "tax_query" instead of using "category__in" for custom taxonomy.

Answer (score 1):

`category__in` is used for built-in post categories, not for custom taxonomies.

You can try something like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'tribe_events',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => '_EventStartDate',
            'value'   => array( $start_date, $end_date ),
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            'type'    => 'DATE'
        )
    ),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'tribe_events_cat',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => array( 2, 6 )
        )
    )
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: When I comment meta_query, it will return blanks result. Is their is any shortcode which filter events by date and category id

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the tribe_get_events() helper function to retrieve the events. Here are the arguments that the plugin is expecting and can be passed through to find by date.

```
Arr::get( $args, 'start_date' ),
Arr::get( $args, 'startDate' ),
Arr::get( $args, 'starts_after' ),
Arr::get( $args, 'starts_before' ),
Arr::get( $args, 'end_date' ),
Arr::get( $args, 'endDate' ),
Arr::get( $args, 'ends_after' ),
Arr::get( $args, 'ends_before' )
```

Your query would look something like this. Note that the date arguments will accept any values that the PHP function strtotime() would also accept. ie now, today...

```
global $post;
$events = tribe_get_events( [
    'eventDisplay'   => 'custom',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'ends_before'    => 'now',
    'starts_after'   => '2019-08-24 11:00:00',
    'category'       => 'exhibitions'
]);
```

Then, you can loop through the results as you would a typical wp_query. Note that there are plenty of helper functions that the plugin offers. I am including just one to show that they are available. You may have to do some digging in the plugin files to find others. The following tribe_get_start_date() function is located at \common\src\functions\template-tags\date.php

```
foreach ( $events as $post ) {
    setup_postdata( $post );    
    echo '<h4>' . $post->post_title . '</h4>';
    echo '<p>' . tribe_get_start_date( $post ) . '</p>';
}
```